# Dot leaders in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Dot leaders are repeated dots that visually connect a label to the corresponding information on the same line, commonly used in tables of contents but also used in accounting formats, for example:

```
Income ............. $   100,000
Expenses ........... $    80,000
Net Income ......... $    20,000
```

In Excel, you can add dot leaders to any cell as follows:

1. Right click on the cell and select **Format Cells…**.
2. Select the **Number** tab.
3. Under **Category**, select **Custom**.
4. In the **Type** field, input `@ *.`.
5. Click **OK**.

After the cell's content (represented by the `@` in the **Type** field input), this will display a space followed by however many periods it takes to fill the cell, i.e., a dot leader.

Apart from the obvious way of just manually putting in a bunch of periods at the end of each cell, is there a way to do the same thing in Google sheets?

Comment: Since Excel is only mentioned as reference regarding the expected result and it's not required for the solution, IMHO that tag should not included, so I removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one reasonable solution.  While not quite as tidy as the Excel version, it gets the job done:

1. With the cell selected, select **Format** > **Number** > **More Formats** > **Custom number format…**.
2. In the **Custom number formats** input field, insert `@\ .........`, including as many periods as needed to reach the end of the cell.
3. Click **Apply**.
4. With the cell selected, select **Format** > **Text wrapping** > **Clip**.  This will make the dots reach the end of the cell without spilling over.

You can then easily apply that to other cells by pasting formatting only.